# Web api call returns json data with empty fields

Tags: json, flurl

I'm getting some json data using Flurl (function below). My problem is that this returns the expected fields but not the actual data:

[image: screenshot]

The json is at: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

The exact same function worked fine in a separate standalone test app that did not use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

Any ideas why it would return the fields but not the data? Thanks.

```
using System;
using Test.API.Constants;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace Test.API.Controllers
{
    public class TestController
    {
        [Route(ApiControllerRoutes.Test.test)]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<dynamic> GetAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
                return await url.GetJsonListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetJsonListAsync` (without a generic argument) returns `Task<IList<dynamic>>`, so the easiest fix is to use the same return type from your controller, instead of `Task<dynamic>`.

If you want this to be a bit more robust and type-safe, I would skip `dynamic`s altogether and create a `User` class, then use `GetJsonListAsync<User>()` and return `Task<IList<User>>` in your controller. I see there's nested objects involved so you'd actually need several classes to represent the whole structure. [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) is a great tool to assist with this. Just paste in JSON represention of a *single* user (not the whole list) and it'll generate everything for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response Todd. I was able to get the data with GetJsonAsync<User>();